# Логотипы в верху экрана

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Не получается прилепить логотипы к верху экрана, мешает навигация.

```
<div class=" navbar-logo">
  <div class="navbar ">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsive-menu">
      <li>
        <a class="" href="#">069842020</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">COMANDA APEL</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">RO <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">RU</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">EN</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
    <img src="images/logo_one.png" class="img-responsive im_left " alt="">&nbsp;
    <img src="images/logo_two.png" class="img-responsive im_right" alt="">                          
  <div class="text">
    <h1>BMW<br> X5</h1>
    <h2>INCONFUNDABIL</h2>
    <div class="btn">
      VEZI OFERTA
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Если используете bootstap оберните все в div с классом row и внутри создайте два div с классами col-md-6. Например:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```

В эти колонки помещайте уже контент который нужен. Или можно создать свои классы если вы не используете bootstap.

```
<style>
  .wrap:after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: table;
  }
  .left-col {
   float: left;
   width: 50%; 
  }
  .right-col {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
  }
</style>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="left-col"></div>
  <div class="right-col"></div>
</div>
```

В left-col помещаете все что нужно видеть с лева right-col соответственно с права.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.imgs {
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="imgs">
  <img src="images/logo_one.png" class="" alt="">
  <img src="images/logo_two.png" class="" alt="">                          
</div>

<div class=" navbar-logo">
  <div class="navbar ">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsive-menu">
      <li>
        <a class="" href="#">069842020</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">COMANDA APEL</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">RO <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">RU</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">EN</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <h1>BMW<br> X5</h1>
    <h2>INCONFUNDABIL</h2>
    <div class="btn">
      VEZI OFERTA
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS: Тут ширина фрейма маловата, в режиме редактирования всё хорошо. Но и тут видно, что картинки в левом верхнем углу.